# ASP.NET: find control in ListView with ClientId in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, findcontrol, clientid

My problem was asked to you before but I cannot make it work. I need your help, I think.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listvsl">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 150px;" src="<%#Eval("resim") %>" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="in" runat="server" Text="Sol" ClientIDMode="Inherit" OnClick="haraket" Style="width: 75px;" />
            <asp:Button ID="cik" OnClick="haraket" runat="server" Text="Sağ" Style="width: 75px;" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Sil" OnClick="sil_Clickice" Style="width: 150px;" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="aciklax" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Inherit" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Güncelle" ClientIDMode="Inherit" OnClick="yazignc" />
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

> I need to get the `aciklax` TextBox with FindControl when I click "Button12"

```
Button bu = (Button)sender;//Button12's onclick event
string[] falanca = bu.ClientID.ToString().Split('_');
string alcez = falanca[0] + "_" + falanca[1] + "_" + "aciklax" + "_" + falanca[3];
```

This is my method to find the ClientId. I get the ClientId but I cannot get the TextBox control with it. Can you help me ?

Comment: Be careful to format your code and your markup correctly when you ask a question. It helps to understand what you did and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't need to parse the `ClientID` to find the TextBox control. You can use the `NamingContainer` property of the button to find the corresponding ListView item. Then you can find the TextBox in the item, using the original ID specified in the ItemTemplate:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
ListViewItem item = btn.NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
TextBox txt = item.FindControl("aciklax") as TextBox;
```

Comment: this is really magical solution thank you , but i really do not understood english part i am low in english , can you explain it to me easiest language ?

Comment: You are welcome. My best explanation is the code. In short: from the button you can get the item, and from the item you can get the TextBox.

Comment: i do not know this method exist really thank you , but i need one more thing how can i show "aciklax" 's saved value  ?

Comment: i try Eval method Text="<%# Eval("aciklax's value") %>" but ISS warn me

Comment: If the field is called "aciklax", you can fill the TextBox with `Text='<%# Eval("aciklax") %>'`. Please note the outer single quotes `'` and the inner double quotes `"`. (One more note: if the answer solved your problem, you can accept it with the check mark).

Comment: thank you again note : i was not  know how to accept the answer sorry :) found and clicked the accept button

Comment: That's OK. And thank you! Most newcomers don't know that they should accept an answer. :-)